# Load different HTML page based on URL in Django class based view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-class-based-views, django-1.8

Currently my urls.py has this code:

```
login_view = LoginView.as_view()
url(r'^login$', login_view, name='login'),
```

I have written a corresponding LoginView in my views.py:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'auth/login.html'
    form_class = forms.LoginForm
```

Now my requirement is that I want to create a login page for different set of users who would come from a different url. For example `myproject.com/customers`.
I can do it with a new View class. But I want to make it generic and handle it in the same LoginView() class.

Is it possible to catch the url parameter and check that inside LoginView() and load a different login.html page for them? Or is there any other way using which we can handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `FormView` you can override the following method like below in example. Templates is rendered in `render_to_response` method.

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    """
    Returns a response, using the `response_class` for this
    view, with a template rendered with the given context.
    If any keyword arguments are provided, they will be
    passed to the constructor of the response class.
    """

    # Write you logic here
    if self.request.something == "customer":
        template = "customer_login.html"
    else:
        template = "user_login.html"
    #######
    response_kwargs.setdefault('content_type', self.content_type)
    return self.response_class(
        request=self.request,
        template=template,
        context=context,
        using=self.template_engine,
        **response_kwargs
    )
```

For more you can https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/